# ag-grid option for ag-icon-small-right

Tags: ag-grid

Is there an option to override the following in ag-grid with a font-awesome icon?

1. ag-icon-small-right
2. ag-icon-tick

For e.g., I can replace the menu icon on the column headers with:

```
icons: {
 menu: '<i class="fa fa-bars"/>'
}
```

in grid options.

I am looking for something similar on the tick mark and the arrow pointing right.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can do that... Check out the below `ColDef`

```
  {
    headerName: "Age",
    field: "age",
    width: 90,
    enableValue: true,
    icons: {
      menu: '<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"/>',
      sortAscending: "U",
      sortDescending: "D"
    }
  }
```

Live example: **[ag grid custom icon](https://plnkr.co/edit/4kiNCnvWq5T4mL9guogJ?p=preview)**

Hover over the `Age` column to see the desired icon.

[image]

You can try icons from [FontAwesome Cheatsheet](https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet?from=io)

Comment: Thanks. This is a very useful reference.  My question relates to the icons for the following https://image.ibb.co/iqD6pH/Screen_Shot_2018_04_24_at_10_39_35_PM.png